# react-router 1.0: using this.props.children instead of the RouteHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm trying to upgrade from react-router 0.13 to 1.0.  I read through the guide and believe I have everything set up properly, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined
```

The error corresponds to this function in react-router:

```
    function createRoutesFromReactChildren(children, parentRoute) {
  var routes = [];

  _react2['default'].Children.forEach(children, function (element) {
    if (_react2['default'].isValidElement(element)) {
      // Component classes may have a static create* method.
      if (element.type.createRouteFromReactElement) {
        var route = element.type.createRouteFromReactElement(element, parentRoute);

        if (route) routes.push(route);
      } else {
        routes.push(createRouteFromReactElement(element));
      }
    }
  });

  return routes;
}
```

Presumably this means that the routes are not getting passed as `this.props.children` properly?

If it helps, here is what my routes look like:

```
var routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={AppView}>
    <Route path="account" component={Account} />
    <Route path="insights" component={InsightsHome} />
    <Route path="insights/:slug" component={SingleInsight} />

    <Route path="collections" component={CollectionBox}>
      <Route path="/:id" component={CollectionContent} />
      <DefaultRoute component={NoCollections} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="team" component={Team} />

    <Redirect from="projects/:projectId/insights/?" to="insights" />
    <Redirect from="projects/:projectId/insights/:slug/?" to="insights-single" />
    <Redirect from="*" to="insights" />
  </Route>
);
```

Here is my `render` method (I am using Redux):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('site-container')
);
```

And here is the relevant piece of my `AppView` component:

```
return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  },
```

Comment: did you already try to narrow it down and see if only one of those routes is the cause?

Comment: Good call mattclemens .  I was assuming because I was hitting the `insights` route that the other routes would not matter but after removing the other routes and re-trying, things worked.  Going to troubleshoot and see which route specifically is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue probably stems from `DefaultRoute` being replaced with `IndexRoute`

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#linking-to-index-routes